# append inside div tag Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i want to append some images inside my div tag when a button is clicked.

**html div tag**

```
<div id="imagedisplay<?php  echo $unapp->property_id; ?>"></div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.view_image').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var prop_id = $(this).data('property-id');

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url:"<?php echo base_url('admin_baman_kumba/images/'); ?>",
        data: {property_id: prop_id},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i].name);
                $('#imagedisplay'+ prop_id+'').prepend('<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/upload_images/"'+ data[i][name] +'" data-lightbox="property">Image #'+ i +'</a>');
            };
        }
    });
});
```

Ajax works fine. this is the result i get when `console.log(data);` is executed.

```
Object { total: Array[6] }
```

inside the object i have

[image]

My problem is images are not getting appended to div tag, i don’t get any errors.
can someone help me to fix this issue . tnx.

Comment: Is `console.log(data[i].name);` logging the image url to the console in the for loop?

Comment: Additionally, your question says that you want to _append images_, but your code is _prepending links_. Which is the desired functionality?

Comment: i tried  `console.log(data[i].name);` `console.log(data[i]->name);`  its not logging the image url.

Comment: @IronFlare, i tried append also that’s also not working.

Comment: Okay, I'm just trying to go through the code now to attempt to find things that could potentially be amiss. `$(this).data('property-id');` should get the clicked element's (`.view-image`) `data-property-id` attribute. Is this your intention?

Comment: what is the desired output structure? `a`s with their `hrefs` set to image url and `img` inside? At the moment it seems image url inside `a` tags and their href set to your `base_url`. Are the `a` tags added to the container?

Comment: @IronFlare, yes you are right , when view image is clicked i get the property-id and using ajax i get the images related to that id in to `data`. thats works fine

Comment: @Samurai i am using light box, light box expect this format `<a href="img/image-2.jpg" data-lightbox="roadtrip">Image #2</a>` for images

Comment: can you guys, please tell me why `console.log(data[i]->name);` is not working or any other ways to output the name

Comment: @SathyaBaman it's data[i].name or data[i]['name']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `data` is not an array as i can see in your `object`. the array is `total` inside `data`.
So the `for()` loop should run on length of `data.total`.

And secondly, in `for` loop replace `data` with `data.total`

Comment: Can't believe I missed that the data was nested inside `total`. This should definitely resolve the issue. +1.